# Streaming data to a WebGL shader

Tags: javascript, video, webgl, shader

I am working within a browser context, with camera images being streamed over a binary SocketIO channel.

The camera I am dealing with only supports outputting its data in [bayer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter) format (as a very large byte array), as shown below:

[image: bayer format]

I wish to display the camera image stream in real time on a canvas in the browser.

My idea so far is to use WebGL as the renderer (for speed), and perform the [conversion](http://pixinsight.com/doc/tools/Debayer/Debayer.html) from bayer to RGBA within the fragment shader.

I am fairly new to WebGL so I am unsure of the conventions and best practices to send the unconverted camera image to the GPU and access it so I can perform the conversion and shade the fragment.

It seems a common technique is sending it as a texture and access it via a texture sampler such as texture2d? But this appears to assume RGBA format, where as bayer format is a completely different structure and it would be more useful to just be able to access the raw byte array.

Pointing in the right direction would be sufficient. I guess the real question is '**How do I send arbitrary data to the GPU and access it in a WebGL context?**'

Edit: I'd rather know the raw WebGL techniques than something using a library such as ThreeJS, although I will likely implement it in ThreeJS if it is particularly easier.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're ask someone to teach you WebGL. It's a big topic and too large for a StackOverflow question. I'd wouldn't be surprised if your question is closed for being too broad.

Read http://webglfundamentals.org or http://learningwebgl.org or one of the many other sites.

After you've learned WebGL then the way to get camera data to the WebGL is by calling `gl.texImage2D` or `gl.texSubImage2D`. There's many examples around the web of passing in camera data to WebGL, although almost all of those get the camera data from the browser, not from a socket. But at a basic level it's no different. Get your data into a TypedArray like a `Uint8Array` and call `gl.texImage2D` to copy that data to a texture.

Comment: Hi, I have done these tutorials and am quite comfortable with them. I believe you have misinterpreted my question. Loading textures is not a problem, it is loading data 'of arbitrary nature' that is the problem. My 'texture' in this case is NOT rgba, so it does not fit well with the standard texture2D() sampler method (that returns a vec4). I am new to WebGL so I do not know the conventions, but I am not looking for a tutorial.

Comment: @BrendanAnnable You have to convert it in the shader. Pick a format you feel most comfortable with as a basis for the conversion. Also sample from the center of the pixel, and there is no dynamic array index access. https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml

Comment: @Winchestro The papers and examples I've read so far use GL_LUMINANCE as it 'kind of' works like a simple array if you use texture2D().r - this seems like a hack but if there is no other way it will have to do.

Comment: @BrendanAnnable sounds reasonable. start with that, you can optimize it to save 3/4 of the memory later once the rest works :)

Comment: Is that not already using the minimal amount of memory? I'd rather design it properly sooner than later.

Comment: Camera's usually take pictures in rectangles (a 2 dimensional array of data). A Textures is a 2 dimensional array of data so I'm kind of lost of what you're not understanding. If you have 1 channel of data make a 1 channel texture like `LUMINANCE` or `ALPHA`. If you have 2 channels of data use `LUMINANCE_ALPHA`. If you have 3 channels of data use `RGB`, if you have 4 use `RGBA`. If your data can't fit into bytes use `FLOAT` although you'll have to check if it's supported. WebGL doesn't care what data you put in a texture or how you use that data.

Comment: @gman You're still not understanding my question. The idea was to get an understanding on the conventions on loading arbitrary 1D data to the GPU. From what I have read (what what your post confirms), is that the standard way is to load the data into a texture and set it's type to LUMINANCE (for 1D data). Frankly, if you do not come from a background of GPU computing, that sounds utterly absurd as the data may not actually be a texture, nor be anything to do with the luminance. I was hoping there was a more generic method, maybe with more generic naming conventions, but this will do.

Comment: There's isn't. WebGL stands for Web **GRAPHICS** LIBRARY. It started with Textures back in 1992. A texture generally happens to be a 2 dimensional array of data so people started using them for things other than "texture data". But the API is > 20 years old and those names like LUMINANCE instead of say "1_CHANNEL_TEXTURE" have stuck around to be backward compatible. You don't like, fine. `gl.1_CHANNEL_TEXTURE = gl.LUMINANCE`. Now you can use some other term. Oh, LUMINANCE is a 1 channel texture, not a 1D texture.

Comment: In WebGL there is no 1D format. Put your 1D data in 2D and reference the data out of the texture with `vec2 tc = vec2(mod(index, textureWidth) / textureWidth, index / textureHeight / dataHeight); vec4 data = texture2D(dataTexture, tc);`

Comment: [Here's an example of putting vertex data into textures and then referencing the them](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/7t2Dj/). Maybe you can adapt it for your needs